# TYPO3 add classes based on imagecols field

Tags: image, typo3, typoscript

I updated my site from V6 to V8 and now have some problems with content rendering of images.

I use extension bootstrap_core extension, which basically wraps every standard CType with bootstrap grid classes - 'col-sm-6' and like.

However on V8 it is not working, anymore.

Here I attach the typoscript responsible for this behaviour:

```
tt_content.image {
20 {
    caption.1.1.dataWrap = <p class="caption-{field:imagecaption_position}">|</p>
    1 {
        # image styles (rounded, circle)
        params.cObject = CASE
        params.cObject {
            key.field = layout
            # Default is responsive
            default = TEXT
            default.value = class="img-responsive img-content"
            # Normal
            1 = TEXT
            1.value = class="img-content"
            # Rounded corners
            2 = TEXT
            2.value = class="img-rounded img-content"
            3 = TEXT
            3.value = class="img-rounded img-responsive img-content"
            # Circle
            4 = TEXT
            4.value = class="img-circle img-content"
            5 = TEXT
            5.value = class="img-circle img-responsive img-content"
        }
    }
    addClassesCol.ifEmpty =
    addClassesCol.override.cObject = COA
    addClassesCol.override.cObject {
        10 = CASE
        10 {
            key.field = imagecols
            default = TEXT
            default.value = col-md-12
            2 < .default
            2.value = col-md-6 col-sm-6
            3 < .default
            3.value = col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6
            4 < .default
            4.value = col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6
            6 < .default
            6.value = col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4
        }
    }
    addClassesCol.override =
    addClassesCol.override.if {
        isGreaterThan.field = imagecols
        value = 1
    }
    addClassesImage >
    layout {
        default.override >
        default.value = <div class="img-center img-above###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        1.override >
        1.value = <div class="img-right img-above###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        2.override >
        2.value = <div class="img-left img-below###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        8.override >
        8.value = <div class="img-center img-below###CLASSES###">###TEXT######IMAGES###</div>
        9.override >
        9.value = <div class="img-right img-below###CLASSES###">###TEXT######IMAGES###</div>
        10.override >
        10.value = <div class="img-left img-below###CLASSES###">###TEXT######IMAGES###</div>
        17.override >
        17.value = <div class="img-intext-right img-intext###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        18.override >
        18.value = <div class="img-intext-left img-intext###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        25.value = <div class="img-beside-right img-beside###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        25.override >
        25.override = <div class="img-header-{field:header_layout} img-beside-right img-beside###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        25.override.if.isTrue.field = header
        25.override.insertData = 1
        26.value = <div class="img-beside-left img-beside###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        26.override >
        26.override = <div class="img-header-{field:header_layout} img-beside-left img-beside###CLASSES###">###IMAGES######TEXT###</div>
        26.override.if.isTrue.field = header
        26.override.insertData = 1
    }
    rendering {
        singleNoCaption {
            allStdWrap {
                dataWrap = <div class="img-wrap"> | </div>
                dataWrap.override >
                innerWrap.cObject.0.value = <div class="img-center-outer"><div class="img-center-inner"> | </div></div>
                innerWrap.cObject.8.value = <div class="img-center-outer"><div class="img-center-inner"> | </div></div>
            }
            singleStdWrap {
                wrap = <figure class="image###CLASSES###">|</figure>
                wrap {
                    override = <figure class="image lightbox###CLASSES###">|</figure>
                    override.if {
                        value = 1
                        equals.field = image_zoom
                        equals.data >
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        noCaption {
            allStdWrap {
                dataWrap = <div class="img-wrap"> | </div>
                dataWrap.override >
            }
            singleStdWrap {
                wrap = <figure class="image###CLASSES###">|</figure>
                wrap {
                    override = <figure class="image lightbox###CLASSES###">|</figure>
                    override.if {
                        value = 1
                        equals.field = image_zoom
                        equals.data >
                    }
                }
            }
            rowStdWrap.wrap = <div class="row row-images"> | </div>
            noRowsStdWrap.wrap = <div class="row row-images"> | </div>
            lastRowStdWrap.wrap = <div class="row row-images"> | </div>
            columnStdWrap.wrap = <div class="col-image###CLASSES###"> | </div>
        }
        singleCaption {
            singleStdWrap {
                wrap = <figure class="image###CLASSES###">|###CAPTION###</figure>
                wrap {
                    override = <figure class="image lightbox###CLASSES###">|###CAPTION###</figure>
                    override.if {
                        value = 1
                        equals.field = image_zoom
                        equals.data >
                    }
                }
            }
            caption {
                wrap = <figcaption class="caption"> | </figcaption>
                wrap.override >
            }
        }
        splitCaption {
            singleStdWrap {
                wrap = <figure class="image###CLASSES###">|###CAPTION###</figure>
                wrap {
                    override = <figure class="image lightbox###CLASSES###">|###CAPTION###</figure>
                    override.if {
                        value = 1
                        equals.field = image_zoom
                        equals.data >
                    }
                }
            }
            caption {
                wrap = <figcaption class="caption"> | </figcaption>
                wrap.override >
            }
            rowStdWrap.wrap = <div class="row row-images"> | </div>
            noRowsStdWrap.wrap = <div class="row row-images"> | </div>
            lastRowStdWrap.wrap = <div class="row row-images"> | </div>
            columnStdWrap.wrap = <div class="col-image###CLASSES###"> | </div>
        }
        globalCaption {
            allStdWrap {
                dataWrap = <figure class="img-wrap"> | ###CAPTION###</figure>
            }
            singleStdWrap {
                wrap = <div class="image###CLASSES###"> | </div>
                wrap {
                    override = <div class="image lightbox###CLASSES###">|</div>
                    override.if {
                        value = 1
                        equals.field = image_zoom
                        equals.data >
                    }
                }
            }
            caption.wrap = <figcaption class="caption"> | </figcaption>
            rowStdWrap.wrap = <div class="row row-images"> | </div>
            noRowsStdWrap.wrap = <div class="row row-images"> | </div>
            lastRowStdWrap.wrap = <div class="row row-images"> | </div>
            columnStdWrap.wrap = <div class="col-image###CLASSES###"> | </div>
        }
    }
}
```

I know that now on V8 there is no section_frame, but rather frame_class. here is the typoscript for the frames:

```
tt_content.stdWrap {
    # related to section_frame
    innerWrap.cObject {
        # Special wraps for specific frames
        default {
            10 {
                cObject {
                    default.value = <div
                    default.override = <div id="c{field:uid}"
                    default.override.if {
                        value = 1
                        equals.field = sectionIndex
                    }
                    menu.value = <nav id="c{field:uid}"
                    menu.override >
                }
            }
            20.10.value >

            # responsive visibility settings
            20.15 = TEXT
            20.15.value.field = tx_bootstrapcore_visibility
            20.15.noTrimWrap = | | |
            20.15.required = 1

            30 {
                cObject {
                    menu.value = >|</nav>
                    menu.override >
                    default.value >
                    default = CASE
                    default {
                        key.field = frame_class
                        default = TEXT
                        default.value = >|</div>
                        # Add  close button for alert boxes
                        40 = TEXT
                        40.value = ><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>|</div>
                        41 < .40
                        42 < .40
                        43 < .40
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        # Ruler before
        5.5 = TEXT
        5.5.value = <hr>

        # Ruler after
        6.35 = TEXT
        6.35.value = <hr>

        # Indent
        10 {
            5 = TEXT
            5.value = <div class="row">
            20.10.value = col-xs-11 col-xs-push-1
            35 = TEXT
            35.value = </div>
        }
        # Indent 33/66
        11 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.10
        11.20.10.value = col-xs-8 col-xs-push-4
        # Indent 66/33
        12 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.10
        12.20.10.value = frame col-xs-8

        # Jumbotron
        20.20.10.value = jumbotron
        # Wells
        21.20.10.value = well
        22 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
        22.20.10.value = well well-sm
        23 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
        23.20.10.value = well well-lg

        # Alerts
        40 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
        40.20.10.value = alert alert-info
        41 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
        41.20.10.value = alert alert-success
        42 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
        42.20.10.value = alert alert-warning
        43 =< tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default
        43.20.10.value = alert alert-danger

        # anchor only if sectionIndex is used
        66.10 {
            value =
            override = <a id="c{field:uid}"></a>
            override.if.value = 1
            override.if.equals.field = sectionIndex
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the key.field from section_frame to class_frame.

However the rendering is still not working.

If additional information needs to be provided, no problem.

Comment: `class_frame` or `frame_class`?  have you verified that you use the same values? and have you converted the values of the old field to the new field?

Comment: Sorry, a typo, it is frame_class. I did not do any conversion, could you provide more information on this, please ?

Comment: I have not used V8 yet, but if the field changes the values needs to be transfered to the new field. and with the change the default values could have been changed too. if you inserted the values by yourself you might need to convert the values on your own.

Comment: It appears that frames work correctly. Could it be that addClassesCol is deprecated or the functionality changed? because when I change addClassesCol to addClasses, I get some wraps, however not like it was previously.

Comment: 'til now each major version had it's changes to the default rendering. either you need to use a compatibility layer or you need to adapt your changes to this new rendering. (And sorry: as said I have no experience with V8 yet)

Comment: Now I am getting : 
<div id="c769" class="csc-default ctype-image teaserbox reviewimg">
        <div class="img-center img-above col-md-6 col-sm-6"> ... </div> </div>
But it should be like this: 
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ">
    <div id="c769" class="csc-default ctype-image teaserbox reviewimg"> ... </div> </div>
The bootstrap classes should be wrapped around ctype, rather than in ctype